# gluSpheres looking oblong

Tags: opengl

I seem to have the same problem mentioned [here](http://www.bitchx.com/log/opengl-f/opengl-f-12-Dec-2009/opengl-f-12-Dec-2009-01.php) (search "`why are my spheres distorted when they get near the edge of the window?`", since there is a lot of irrelevant discussion). The solution in that link was drastically decreasing the FOV to 10, which seems to make my scene be quite shallow in the z direction. Somebody else mentioned that the aspect ratio may be off, but I'm not very sure about that:

```
gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1, -200);
```

Anyways, at an FOV of 60, my scene looks like this:

[image: boo]

Changing it to 45 helps, but the spheres still look distorted near the edges. Why is this? Is this distortion inevitable?

Comment: Well getting perspective right is not an easy task. Unless I'm able to formulate a good answer (or somebody else does), let me just mention that the zFar parameter to gluPerspective should be a **positive** value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this?

This is the way a affine perspective projection works.

> Is this distortion inevitable?

In the case of a affine projection yes.

However using a vertex shader you can implement angle based projections. However those require the geometry to be sufficiently tesselated. Long straigt edges (like those of your background box) must be broken down. A tesselation shader can help. Another way is to render into a cube map 5 quadratic views of 90° FOV, then draw from that cubemap a angular projection.